# delete from callLog - Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, cursor, calllog

I have this code to delete a `Call`from `CallLog.Calls`provider :

```
            String strNumber= "myPhoneNumber"

            String queryString= "NUMBER='" + strNumber + "'";

            Log.v("Number", queryString); 

            int i=context.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, queryString, null); 
            if(i<1) 

            {  
               // do my stuff
            }
```

This code work on android 2.2 but it does'nt work on android 2.3.3

There'is no error in the LogCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the contract class provided by the SDK ( [CallLog.Calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) in your situation ) when building your queries.

The contract classes are meant to map the object model to the corresponding data names in the database. When the android team need to update a column name in the database, they also update the contract class and then no change is required for developpers.

Then try to change you query string to :

```
String queryString = CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + "='" + strNumber + "'";
```

NOTE: the single-quote marks are necessary.

Also make sure the number is exactly matching the database number.

> ( +33678541236 != 0678541236 )

To be sure to delete the correct row you can do the following :

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ? ", strNumber , "");
int idOfRowToDelete = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(idOfRowToDelete)), "", null);
```

(didn't try it but should work with small corrections)

Comment: My mistake was myPhoneNumber doesn't much the `NUMBER`in the database . like in your example. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

```
private void deleteNumber() {
            try {
                String strNumberOne[] = { "00577698160" };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ? ", strNumberOne, "");
                boolean bol = cursor.moveToFirst();
                if (bol) {
                    do {
                        int idOfRowToDelete = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));
                        getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(idOfRowToDelete)), "", null);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.print("Exception here ");
            }
        }
```